# Stop openpyxl from inserting curly brackets into excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm currently working on a project that reads from an Excel sheet with the openpyxl library, edits some of the data in the file, and then recreates a new one with the edited data.

My main issue is that when I save the new file, a lot of the excel functions I previously had are saved with curly brackets around them like this:
`{=INDEX(M98:O98, MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(M98:O98),0))}`
This is completely breaking the functionality of the excel sheet.

At first I wondered if this was an issue with how I was updating each individual cell. However, I commented out my entire function besides opening the file, and saving the new one, with no edits done, and I'm still getting the issue. The code now looks like this now:

```
def update(filename):
    # Open excel sheet
    e_workload = load_workbook(filename, data_only=False)
    # Save results
    e_workload.save(filename.replace(".xlsx", "_EDITED.xlsx"))
    e_workload.close()
```

I'm just wondering what is causing this issue and how to fix it. I'm wondering if it's an issue with the library, but I don't want to rewrite my entire program without determining what the issue is first.

Comment: The curly brackets are inserted by Excel for some types of formula.